# Searchkick aggregations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I have the following two aggregations in Rails using searchkick gem. When I used any of them separately, it works like a charm. But I want to "merge" them together and cannot figure out how to do it :(.

**Aggregation 1:**

```
aggs: { price_vat: { ranges: [{to: 5}, {from: 5, to: 10}, {from: 10}] } }
```

**Aggregation 2:**

```
aggs: ['property_options.property_id', 'property_options.id', 'property_options.value_cs', 'property_options.value_en', 'manufacturer_id']
```

Is there any expert on this who knows how to do it?
Really appreciated. Thank you and have a good weekend, Miro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to the define the "aggs" as hashes. Then you can easily merge them together.

example:

```
range_aggregations = { price_vat: { ranges: [{to: 5}, {from: 5, to: 10}, {from: 10}] } }
base_aggregations = {
   property_options.property_id: {},
   property_options.id: {}
}
```

Now merge them togehter:

```ruby
range_aggregations.merge(base_aggregations)
```